# How to create object of type interface in angular 4?

Tags: angular, object, angular2-directives

I am working on a single page shopping store but stuck in a small problem. I have been trying to define an object of type interface but I am unable to save any value in this object.

This is my code

```
interface ICartItem2 {
    total_items: number;
    total_sum: number;
}

    items: Array<ICartItem> = []; //array of objects working fine
    totals:  ICartItem2; //this is my faulty object of type interface ICartItem2 
    total_items:number=0;
    total_sum:number = 0;
    cart: ICartItem;
    broadcast_obj = {items:[],totals:{}}; //object to store array of objects and single object
```

The main problem is this line

```
totals:  ICartItem2;
```

It shows no error at declaration, but at the following line when I am storing values in this object and then showing main object it is showing undefined.

```
this.totals = {total_items:this.total_items,total_sum:this.total_sum}

console.log(this.broadcast_obj.totals); // showing undefined
```

I have done same with array of objects and it is working fine

```
this.cart = {id:id, name: itemText, price: amount,quantity:1};
this.items.push(this.cart);
```

and when I show in console(this.broadcast_obj.items); //it shows fine.

Here is the full code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
interface ICartItem {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
}
interface ICartItem2 {
    total_items: number;
    total_sum: number;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    items: Array<ICartItem> = []; 
    totals:  ICartItem2;
    total_items:number=0;
    total_sum:number = 0;
    cart: ICartItem;
    broadcast_obj = {items:[],totals:{}};
    duplicate:ICartItem ;
    constructor(private _data: DataService) {  }

    ngOnInit() {
        //this.items_count = this.cart.length;
        this._data.cast.subscribe(res => this.broadcast_obj = res);
        this._data.changeCart(this.broadcast_obj);
    }

    additem(id,itemText,amount){
        if(this.items.length==0){//no item in the array
            this.cart = {id:id, name: itemText, price: amount,quantity:1};
            this.items.push(this.cart);
        }
        else{
            this.duplicate = this.items.find(x => x.id == id);//check if item already exists in the cart
            if (this.duplicate === null || this.duplicate === undefined) { //item object not found in the array
                this.cart = {id:id, name: itemText, price: amount,quantity:1};
                this.items.push(this.cart);
            }
            else if(this.duplicate.id===id){
                this.duplicate.quantity++;
            }
        }

        this.broadcast_obj.items = this.items;
        this.total_items++;
        this.total_sum += amount;
        this.totals = {total_items:this.total_items,total_sum:this.total_sum}

        console.log(this.broadcast_obj.totals);
        this._data.changeCart(this.broadcast_obj);
    }

}
```

Code of header component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

interface ICartItem {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
}
interface ICartItem2 {
    total_items: number;
    total_sum: number;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    cart: Array<ICartItem> = [];
    totals:  ICartItem2;
    total_items:number = 0;
    total_sum:number = 0;
    showHide: false; 
    constructor(private _data: DataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._data.cast.subscribe(res =>{
            this.cart = res.items;
            this.total_items = res.totals.total_items;
            //this.total_sum =   res.totals.total_sum;
        });
    }

    addClass(toggle) {
        console.log(this.total_items);
        this.showHide = toggle;
    }

}
```

service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private cartobj = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
    cast = this.cartobj.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    changeCart(item_param) {
        this.cartobj.next(item_param);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are debug on different objects. this.totals = {total_items:this.total_items,total_sum:this.total_sum}

console.log(this.broadcast_obj.totals); // showing undefined
It's 'this.totals' or 'this.broadcast_obj.totals'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating the `items` property of `this.broadcast_obj` with `this.items`. But you are leaving `totals` property uninitialized. Thus it is showing as undefined.
If you do `console.log(this.totals)` you will get the correct output. I believe you need to add `this.broadcast_obj.totals = this.totals;` after `this.totals = {total_items:this.total_items,total_sum:this.total_sum}`

**EDIT**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
interface ICartItem {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
}
interface ICartItem2 {
    total_items: number;
    total_sum: number;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    items: Array<ICartItem> = []; 
    totals:  ICartItem2;
    total_items:number=0;
    total_sum:number = 0;
    cart: ICartItem;
    broadcast_obj = {items:[],totals:{}};
    duplicate:ICartItem ;
    constructor(private _data: DataService) {  }

    ngOnInit() {
        //this.items_count = this.cart.length;
        this._data.cast.subscribe(res => this.broadcast_obj = res);
        this._data.changeCart(this.broadcast_obj);
    }

    additem(id,itemText,amount){
        if(this.items.length==0){//no item in the array
            this.cart = {id:id, name: itemText, price: amount,quantity:1};
            this.items.push(this.cart);
        }
        else{
            this.duplicate = this.items.find(x => x.id == id);//check if item already exists in the cart
            if (this.duplicate === null || this.duplicate === undefined) { //item object not found in the array
                this.cart = {id:id, name: itemText, price: amount,quantity:1};
                this.items.push(this.cart);
            }
            else if(this.duplicate.id===id){
                this.duplicate.quantity++;
            }
        }

        this.broadcast_obj.items = this.items;
        this.total_items++;
        this.total_sum += amount;
        this.totals = {total_items:this.total_items,total_sum:this.total_sum}
        console.log(this.totals)            //Should give you valid log
        this.broadcast_obj.totals = this.totals; //Added as per my answer
        console.log(this.broadcast_obj.totals);
        this._data.changeCart(this.broadcast_obj);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have changed the code as you suggested but now the new error is showing

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'total_items' of undefined

I have added the code in the end of the question.

Comment: Hmm..that's weird cause I didn't change anything related to `total_items` in my answer. I will edit and add the full code as it should be.

Comment: dear the error is still the same. It is not in the home component in which you are changing. It is showing in the header component as I have added the code .

Comment: Your question was on the home component to which I have replied the fix and the reasons. The header component is using a service, one which I have no idea how it looks. I can only guess that your service is returning `res.totals` as `null`.

Comment: my friend I appreciate your help and I agree with you. Please help me a little bit more so that I can fully solve this problem.I have edited the question and added the header component and service code at the end.

Comment: What you gotta do here is make sure that a property exists on an object before using it. In your service you `cast` is an observable on `any`. When your header or any other component calls the service and listens to the observable, it will initially get one of type `any`. Thus if you do `res.totals` it will come out as `undefined` since `res` being of type `any` doesn't have a property called `totals`. And when you are doing `res.totals.total_items` you are essentially trying to find a property called `total_items` on an undefined object which results in an error.
TL;DR: do a `if(res.totals)`

Comment: Can I make any change in service to avoid this error? or still I should use type any?